# Documents not showing in Cosmos Emulator

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-storage-explorer, azure-cosmosdb-emulator

I'm using the Cosmos Emulator (v. 2.11.13.0) to develop locally.
My program works fine with the emulator, but the stored documents don't show up in the document explorer:

[image]

I can see the documents just fine using Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer (v. 1.16.0):

[image]

The Cosmos DB Accounts explorer in Storage Explorer is deprecated - which is also why I'm afraid to update it to a newer version.

I can create new documents via the [Azure Cosmos DB Emulator](https://localhost:8081/_explorer/index.html) explorer and save them.
Then they show up in the UI:

[image]

But when I click the update icon, they immediately disappear from the list (though the info is still visible in the details panel):

[image]

The document continues to exist when viewed in the Storage Explorer.

I've tried doing as clean an install as possible and used multiple different versions:

- I've uninstalled the program via "Apps & Features"
- I've removed all files in

  - %LOCALAPPDATA%/CosmosDBEmulator
  - %PROGRAMFILES%/Azure Cosmos DB Emulator
- I've tried version:

  - 2.11.13
  - 2.9.0
  - 2.7.2

Comment: From your screenshot, it seems you're connecting to Cosmos DB Emulator in Storage Explorer but a real Cosmos DB account in Cosmos DB Explorer.

Comment: @GauravMantri No, it is the same local one. I can create new collections in the Storage Explorer and it will show up in the explorer in the browser. I can also create items in the Cosmos Explorer and see them on the list, but as soon as I refresh the list, the items disappear.

Comment: Out of interest, what is the TTL on the container, and the items themselves - are they possibly being deleted by some strange value here?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/time-to-live

Comment: @leon So the documents aren't being deleted; they just don't show in the UI. I'm able to retrieve them using queries in code and see them in the Storage Explorer.

Comment: @serhat No,I don't think I ever find a solution. I've since gotten a new computer, but I don't consider that the best solution to that problem...